# Outlining a piece of text in Illustrator or Indesign

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

[image: Outline]

Hello, I want to make a nice outline or stroke effect, preferably in Indesign. I have tried to make the stroke thicker but it just makes the centre of the word/writing thinner in colour. I want to outline the whole word (like the white area).

Comment: Best result comes with Illustrator: Object > Path >Shift path (4th option). Thereby you expand the path in a more organic way, then you just push the result in the way your light comes down. You can do that multiple times and change colors from light(top) to darker ones (bottom)

Comment: @DodieEslava: Please do not post answers as comments.

Comment: @Daiaiai: Please do not post answers as comments.

Answer (score 2):

This can all easily be accomplished by using the **Appearance Panel** in **Illustrator** with additional fills and strokes. Then applying `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform` to the additional items.

Essentially It's all done in the Appearance panel.

[image]

After you've set this up, be certain to drag the type to the **Graphic Styles Panel**. That way, in the future, you can merely type some text and click the Graphic Style to apply the same effect.

Note that while InDesign has some drawing options, this is *much* better and more easily accomplished within Illustrator. InDesign would require duplicating objects and moving them, because you can't control stacking order of strokes and fills in InDesign.